# Robot framework using selenium library need to select and replace the date from input text field

Tags: javascript, python, java, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to set a date value in our internal web page. Existing setup is that field is associated with a datePicker (React Material UI --- which we don't have control over) and comes with a default value as today`s date and time. My requirement is to change the date and time using a string. I tried clearing the text element and giving Input text keywords, but didn't work. Manually I can click on that field and selecting the field content using (command + a --- MAC OS) and replace the text. So, Tried to do the same with Keywords Press Keys, but it is also not working. Below is my sample statements. Can anyone help/suggest on how we can achieve setting the value for date and time.

```
Clear Element Text    //*[@id="inputfieldId"]/locator-path
Input Text    //*[@id="inputfieldId"]/locator-path    ${fromDate}



Press Keys    //*[@id="inputfieldId"]/locator-path    \CMD+a
Input Text    //*[@id="inputfieldId"]/locator-path    ${fromDate}
```

Comment: Try by entering with correct date format. It should work.